# Float right and left are on the same line

Tags: css, twig

The first image and the file label are on the same line, but the last image is on a second line.

I would like the three items to be on the same line.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
      <img src="{{asset('bundles/cramifaccueil/images/pdfdocument.png')}}"  
                         title="{% trans %}dialog.pdf.file{% endtrans %}"
                         class="smallImagesFloatLeft"
                         />
      <div class="fileLabel">{% trans %}file.note.service.2584{% endtrans %}</div>
      <img src="{{asset('bundles/cramifaccueil/images/download.png')}}" 
                        title="{% trans %}download{% endtrans %}"
                        class="smallImagesFloatRight"
                        />
</div>
<div>
      <img src="{{asset('bundles/cramifaccueil/images/pdfdocument.png')}}" 
                        title="{% trans %}dialog.pdf.file{% endtrans %}"
                        class="smallImagesFloatLeft"
                        />
      <div class="fileLabel">{% trans %}file.mode.operatoire{% endtrans %}</div>
      <img src="{{asset('bundles/cramifaccueil/images/download.png')}}" 
                        title="{% trans %}download{% endtrans %}"
                        class="smallImagesFloatRight"
                        />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.smallImagesFloatLeft {
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
  cursor: default;
}

.smallImagesFloatRight{
  float:right;
}

.fileLabel {
 max-width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the actual HTML? Offhand, it sounds like there just isn't enough space on one line to hold all the elements.

Comment: there is space enough

Comment: Totally depends on your circumstances. If you know the sizes of your images, just set a height on your divs, and the problem is fixed. Technically speaking, all three items are on the same "line", but there is not enough height to fit them all on, so the last item is moved downwards.

Comment: @mlwacosmos Without seeing the problem we can't tell.

Comment: I checked everything with firebug... there is space enough.. the fact is that the last image is going on another line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is room on one line, you simply need to re-order your elements so that the floats come before the non-floated element:

```
<div>
      <img src="{{asset('bundles/cramifaccueil/images/pdfdocument.png')}}"  
                         title="{% trans %}dialog.pdf.file{% endtrans %}"
                         class="smallImagesFloatLeft"
                         />
     <img src="{{asset('bundles/cramifaccueil/images/download.png')}}" 
                        title="{% trans %}download{% endtrans %}"
                        class="smallImagesFloatRight"
                        />
     <div class="fileLabel">{% trans %}file.note.service.2584{% endtrans %}</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o0ksu724/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to `float:left` your `.fileLabel`.

just remember to use a `clear:both` after your floated elements.

```
<span style='clear:both'></span>
```

just add this inside the parent div after all your floated elements.

Comment: well, then i think there should be something messing your code, here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0oaLqstw/) of the code working.

Comment: I've done a fix to make it works better [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0oaLqstw/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, It would be a lot better if you provided us a fiddle to understand in a better way that what are you actually getting from the code and what do you expect from it.

I believe there can be 2 reasons for the images not appearing on the same line are:

1. Images are too big to fit the size of the page so they are forced to move on the second line. If that is the case, then, obviously you'll have to reduce the size of images.
2. There may be coding issues and for that I think you should use

   `position: absolute`

   the following line of code first in the desired image and property first and then check if its working or not.
3. Also, I would like to tell you what I do usually to solve these kinds of problems. Choose some background color of the div tags `background: red`to see where and how much spaces these divs are taking on the page and then move further with that.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I realized the only thing to do is to add :

```
display: inline
```

on the fileLabel class